# Convert angle to vector NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I have angle A in netlogo. Which is the turtle's heading?
I wish to convert to it to unit vector.
How should I do it given the turtle's axis are different from that normal?(Heading 0 corresponds to looking forward).

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do here. Heading 0 corresponds to pointing 'up' the screen (from bottom to top), 90 is to the right etc. The heading of a turtle describes which way it is looking so if it is looking right it has heading 90. Try doing an inspect on one of your turtles and you will see this for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that by "unit vector" you want a x component and a y component, the `dx` and `dy` primitives do this (see [dictionary](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/5.1.0/docs/dictionary.html#dx)). So for example:

```
observer> crt 1 [ set heading 30 print (list dx dy) ]
[0.49999999999999994 0.8660254037844387]
```

Note that `dx` is just `sin heading` and `dy` is just `cos heading`.

Comment: Thanks! sin corresponds to x and cos to y as the angles with the vertical.